# FusionCharts fatal error undefined function FC_SetRenderer()

Tags: php, mysql

Dear please help me to do this,

i am biginer in FusionCharts. while creating chat using FusionCharts i get a fatal error like.

Call to undefined function FC_SetRenderer() in C:\xampp\htdocs\chart\sample3\DrillDown_Child_Chart.php on line 49

line 49 is given below

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Set the rendering mode to JavaScript
        FC_SetRenderer('javascript');

        // Call the renderChart method, which would return the HTML and JavaScript required to generate the chart
        echo renderChart('Charts/Column2D.swf', // Path to chart type
                '',     // Empty string when using Data String method
                $strXML,// Variable which has the chart data
                'top10_most_populous_cities', // Unique chart ID
                '660', '400', // Width and height in pixels
                false,  // Disable debug mode
                true    // Enable 'Register with JavaScript' (Recommended)
            );
```

Comment: line 49 is given above

Comment: Instead of FC_SetRenderer, try `FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('JavaScript');`.

Comment: Dears thanks .,
now i got these error.. 
Notice: Use of undefined constant FusionCharts - assumed 'FusionCharts' in C:\xampp\htdocs\chart1\testing.php on line 43

Fatal error: Call to undefined function setCurrentRenderer() in C:\xampp\htdocs\chart1\testing.php on line 43

Comment: Most likely, you have not included the fusioncharts.js in your page. Please read [this](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/installation.html)